# Invalid parameter "tool" Jenkins build warnings Ng plugin

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to add static analysis tools plugin Warnings Next Generation to my pipeline Jenkinsfile.

I followed what was written on their GitHub page

https://github.com/jenkinsci/warnings-ng-plugin/blob/master/doc/Documentation.md

but when I try to add

```
post {
        always {
            junit testResults: '**/target/surefire-reports/TEST-*.xml'

            recordIssues enabledForFailure: true, tools: [mavenConsole(), java(), javaDoc()]
            recordIssues enabledForFailure: true, tool: checkStyle()
            recordIssues enabledForFailure: true, tool: spotBugs()
            recordIssues enabledForFailure: true, tool: cpd(pattern: '**/target/cpd.xml')
            recordIssues enabledForFailure: true, tool: pmdParser(pattern: '**/target/pmd.xml')
        }
    }
```

And build it, the build fails and shows the following error

Invalid parameter "tool" did you mean tools

I am new to Jenkins CI , please help in resolving this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing the same error. I don't understand why it's happening, both `tool` and `tools` are listed in the [Warnings Next Generation Plugin's Pipeline Reference](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/warnings-ng/). I figured out a workaround, using `tools` and specifying your tool as the single element in the array. This snippet is working for me:

```
post {
    always {
      recordIssues tools: [gcc(pattern: 'myBuildLog.log')]
    }
}
```

For the record, I'm using Warnings Next Generation Plugin 9.10.2 on Jenkins 2.319.1, and this is the error I see:

```
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
WorkflowScript: 30: Invalid parameter "tool", did you mean "tools"? @ line 30, column 22.
           recordIssues tool: gcc(pattern: "build/*.log", name: "GCC warnings", id: "GCC warnings")
                        ^

1 error

    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.failIfErrors(ErrorCollector.java:310)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToPrimaryClassNodes(CompilationUnit.java:1085)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:603)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.processPhaseOperations(CompilationUnit.java:581)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:558)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.doParseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:298)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:268)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parseClass(GroovyShell.java:688)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parse(GroovyShell.java:700)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsGroovyShell.doParse(CpsGroovyShell.java:142)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsGroovyShell.reparse(CpsGroovyShell.java:127)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsFlowExecution.parseScript(CpsFlowExecution.java:571)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsFlowExecution.start(CpsFlowExecution.java:523)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowRun.run(WorkflowRun.java:334)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:99)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:432)
[Bitbucket] Notifying commit build result
[Bitbucket] Build result notified
Finished: FAILURE
```

Original Jenkinsfile contents:

```
stage('Warning analysis') {
  steps {
    recordIssues tool: gcc(pattern: "build/*.log", name: "GCC warnings", id: "GCC warnings")
  }
}
```